# HAML for loop prints the word "true" in HTML rendering

Tags: ruby, haml

I'm printing a list from an array object and when it's done going through all the items in the array, it prints the word "true" in the HTML.

The code looks like this:

```ruby
%ul 
  = for i in users
    %li
      = i.username
```

This prints:

```
username1
username2
username3
true
```

which looks like this in the html output:

```html
<ul>
  <li>username1</li>
  <li>username2</li>
  <li>username3</li>
  true
</ul>
```

Why is that `true` getting printed and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `=` for the loop, which causes the result of the expression to be output. When you want to run Ruby code but not have the value emitted into the output, use `-` instead:

```
%ul 
  - for i in users
    %li
      = i.username
```

This can be written more simply as:

```
%ul 
  - for i in users
    %li= i.username
```

Proof:

```
C:\>haml
- users = %w[user1 user2 user3]
%ul
  - for name in users
    %li= name
^Z
<ul>
  <li>user1</li>
  <li>user2</li>
  <li>user3</li>
</ul>
```

---

As an aside, I personally find this usage of `for` in Ruby abhorrent. Instead I personally recommend:

```
%ul 
  - users.each do |user|
    %li= user.username
```

Comment: That should be "Firstly, secondly **and** finally…". Really don't use `for` because it just uses `each` internally anyway

Comment: you're awesome.  thank you for solving my issue so quickly :-)

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the English critique. Edited. :)

Comment: @Phrogz haha, not an English critique, just a reflection of how much I wanted to emphasise `.each` over `for` ;)